# React - dynamic font size to take all available space

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-size

I'm trying to create a layout like this in my Next.js project:

[image]

There will be a word, an image in between, and then another word, like above. I need to dynamically set the font size in order to take all available space. How can I do this?

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Check this [Fitting Text to a Container](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[textFit](https://github.com/STRML/textFit) It’s JavaScript library that adjusts font sizes to fit text into a container.

[fitty](https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty) is another JS library resizes type to maximize just horizontally

You can find more options here and go with the one suits you best. [Link](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an article that show lots of methods to do that.

https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Libraries you can take a look:

[react-scale-text](https://github.com/datchley/react-scale-text)

[fitty](https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty)

[react-fitty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fitty)

[textFit](https://github.com/STRML/textFit)

[react-textfit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-textfit)

[auto-text-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-text-size?activeTab=readme)